# Managing reusable categories library in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm facing a problem with the multiplication of my projects. I often create categories on existing classes (`NSArray`, `NSString`, `UIView`, etc.) but they are all scattered across my many projects.

I was wondering if there was a way in Xcode of registering (kind of) those categories in order to add them in any project, and access them, a bit like a library of `.h`/`.m` files.

I thought the File Template Library could do the job, but it seems not that simple.

PS: Of course, I'm not talking about library in a programmatic way, like static or dynamic libraries. Just some kind of a store in which I can pick categories I often use...

Comment: You can create a static library. Have a look on this tutorial [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial)

Comment: Thanks but like written in the PS section, I'm not looking for static library...

Comment: Why not a static lib?

Comment: Because this is not my need. I just need some kind of store for my categories in which I can pick, not a lib containing all of them, or worse, a lib by category.

Answer (score 1):

[CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org), in addition to helping manage these kinds of "pick and choose" situations with whole external libraries, also [has the ability for you to keep a private repository of pods](http://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html) from which you can also pick and choose. Its various scripts are pretty slick in terms of adding your selected pods to your Xcode project/workspace, etc.

Depending on the granularity you're looking for, this may be a good option for you.

Comment: I think it's a bit too much for me, I was referring at something much simpler within Xcode. Just some kind of the way the snippets work... But if nothing else shows up, I'll try it.